# Convert 20180918 to 2018-09-18 in Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Given Data Frame:

```
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+
|   user_id|       id|     date|discount|year|
+-----------------+---------+-----------------+
|  44143827|118775509| 20180103|     0.0|2018|                  
|  16445775|118841685| 20180105|     0.0|2018|                  
|  25230573|119388676| 20180111|     0.0|2018|                  
|  44634333|119537508| 20180112|     0.0|2018|
```

I want to convert this date from yyyyMMdd to yyyy-MM-dd. Although i'm able to perform this for single value i.e.

```
scala> val x = "20180918"
x: String = 20180918

scala> x.patch(4,"-",0)
res76: String = 2018-0918

scala> x.patch(4,"-",0).patch(7,"-",0)
res77: String = 2018-09-18
```

But couldn't be able to figure out for the complete data set. Please somebody help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use date_format() and to_timestamp() functions. Check this out:

```
scala> val df = Seq((20180103),(20180105)).toDF("dt")
df: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [dt: int]

scala> df.withColumn("dt",'dt.cast("string")).withColumn("dt",date_format(to_timestamp('dt,"yyyyMMdd"),"yyyy-MM-dd")).show(false)
+----------+
|dt        |
+----------+
|2018-01-03|
|2018-01-05|
+----------+

scala>
```

Note that date_format returns string, if you want it in date datatype, then

```
scala> val df2 = df.withColumn("dt",'dt.cast("string")).withColumn("dt",date_format(to_timestamp('dt,"yyyyMMdd"),"yyyy-MM-dd"))
df2: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [dt: string]

scala> df2.printSchema
root
 |-- dt: string (nullable = true)


scala> val df3 = df2.withColumn("dt",'dt.cast("date"))
df3: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [dt: date]

scala> df3.printSchema
root
 |-- dt: date (nullable = true)


scala> df3.show(false)
+----------+
|dt        |
+----------+
|2018-01-03|
|2018-01-05|
+----------+


scala>
```

Comment: @RishabhOjha..glad that it helped you.. please consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

In Pyspark you could do like below

```
# create a data frame
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(
[
("SirChillingtonIV", "20120104"), 
("Booooooo99900098", "20120104"), 
("Booooooo99900098", "20120106"), 
("OprahWinfreyJr", "20120110"), 
("SirChillingtonIV", "20120111"), 
("SirChillingtonIV", "20120114"), 
("SirChillingtonIV", "20120811")
], 
("user_name", "login_date"))


# Import functions
from pyspark.sql import functions as f

# Create data framew with new column new_date with data in desired format
df1 = df.withColumn("new_date", f.from_unixtime(f.unix_timestamp("login_date",'yyyyMMdd'),'yyyy-MM-dd'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want a String as output, you can create a new UDF to convert the input String from `yyyyMMdd` to `yyyy-MM-dd` format like the following:

```
def dateFormatDef(x: String): String = x.patch(4,"-",0).patch(7,"-",0)
val dateFormat = udf[String, String](dateFormatDef)
```

The output in the String in the expected format:

```
df = df.withColumn("newFormat", dateFormat($"date"))
df.show()
+--------+----------+
|    date| newFormat|
+--------+----------+
|20180103|2018-01-03|
|20180105|2018-01-05|
|20180111|2018-01-11|
|20180112|2018-01-12|
+--------+----------+
```